# AppDomain.AssemblyResolve does not fire

Tags: c#, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I'm trying to use CEF under an AnyCPU configuration. Following the guidelines provided, I am attaching an assembly resolver prior to loading the assembly. However, I get a `BadImageFormatException` when entering the `Load` method, and the `Resolver` method never fires.

I isolated this in a test project, and the Resolver fires as expected, indicating to me that there may be something going on in the main solution causing the assembly to be resolved independent of the `Resolver` method? I'm not sure.

Is there any obvious reason as to why an assembly might already be loaded prior to its first use? Does that apply here?

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        CefSharp.Initialize();
    }
}

static class CefSharp
{
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Initializing");
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += Resolver;
        Debug.WriteLine("Calling load");
        Load();
        Debug.WriteLine("Leaving init");
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    static void Load()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Executing Load");
        var settings = new CefSettings();

        // disable GPU acceleration to prevent screen flicker
        settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu", "1");

        // Set BrowserSubProcessPath based on app bitness at runtime
        settings.BrowserSubprocessPath = Path.Combine(
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase,
            Environment.Is64BitProcess ? "x64" : "x86",
            "CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe");

        // Make sure you set performDependencyCheck false
        Cef.Initialize(settings, performDependencyCheck: false, browserProcessHandler: null);
    }

    // Will attempt to load missing assembly from either x86 or x64 subdir
    static Assembly Resolver(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Entering Resolver: {args.Name}");

        if (args.Name.StartsWith("CefSharp"))
        {
            string assemblyName = args.Name.Split(new[] { ',' }, 2)[0] + ".dll";
            string archSpecificPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase,
                Environment.Is64BitProcess ? "x64" : "x86",
                assemblyName);

            Debug.WriteLine("Initialized");
            return File.Exists(archSpecificPath)
                ? Assembly.LoadFile(archSpecificPath)
                : null;
        }

        Debug.WriteLine("Resolver Skipping");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to have the event fire.  If it doesn't then the odds you'll have this problem greatly increases because it found the wrong DLL by accident.  Use Fuslogvw.exe and log all binds to find out where it found any managed assemblies, SysInternals' Process Monitor is useful to see it loading unmanaged DLLs.

Comment: @HansPassant Fuxlogvw.exe, configured to log all, shows no relevant bind events. ProcMon, filtered by ProcessName=myApp.exe, Operation=Load Image, does not show any load attempts for the relevant image. ProcMon is unfamiliar to me, should I view from another perspective? Any other hints for additional steps I can take?

Comment: Artifacts existed in my `bin` folder that were not being removed by Clean/Rebuild. After manually cleaning the folder, everything works as expected.